# (Socket.io) How should I optimize number of Namespaces?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, scalability

I am planning on using socket.io to create an online app that allows users to chat via video, and saves each video call/session in a database. (Audio for each of these sessions will be separately available to download as well.)

Because there could be multiple video calls/sessions happening at once, I want to separate the data for each session. Socket.io offers both Namespaces and Rooms to do this, but I am unsure which is more optimal for my problem.

Namespaces, [according to the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Namespaces), are "a useful feature to minimize the number of resources (TCP connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your application by introducing separation between communication channels."

Is it best to have 1 namespace per room/call/session?

Or would it be best to limit tcp connections by creating some rule that will create a new namespace if/when:

> Let's say **MAX_CLIENTS_PER_NAMESPACE** = (the max number of sockets/clients we want in a namespace)

> Say the last/smallest namespace currently has **N** clients (i.e. if you add up the clients from all the rooms in that namespace we get some number **N**), and the new room/call/session to-be-created has **M** clients. Create a new namespace if **M** + **N** >= **MAX_CLIENTS_PER_NAMESPACE**

Comment: Hi @Megan, I'm guessing you don't need to use namespaces here on this purpose. You can basicly use room's instead of namespaces which is way easier to use. In my mind namespaces usually used for seperation of Admin / User. So they can emit and get different type of events.

Comment: @HalilÇakar Ah ok, thank you will try this.